# Refreshing RecyclerView Between Two Tabs

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout

I have two tabs in my app. So when I delete a list from the RecyclerView of one tab it should be added to the RecyclerView. I have deleted the list from the 1st tab and added it to the list of 2nd tab's recyclerview. But, the recyclerview doesnot take the change. When I go to next activity and come back to the tabs, then it shows the change.
In short I just need to update the data sent to the adapter.

I have already used

> notifyDataSetChanged() and swapAdapter()

but did not work.
Do anyone know who to make it work ? 
Thank you
!

Tab 1 Fragment :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_active_patients, container, false);
    activePatientsList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.active_patients_recyclerview);
    activePatientsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    final ActivePatientRecyclerAdapter activePatientRecyclerAdapter = new ActivePatientRecyclerAdapter(getActivity()
            ,activePatientList);

    activePatientRecyclerAdapter.setOptionsCLickedListener(new ActivePatientRecyclerAdapter.OptionsCLickedListener() {
        @Override
        public void popUpClicked(final View view, final int position) {
            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), view);
            MenuInflater menuInflater = popupMenu.getMenuInflater();
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_active_patients_additional_options,
                    popupMenu.getMenu());
            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    int id = menuItem.getItemId();
                    if (id == R.id.action_discharge) {

                        SQLiteDBUse db = new SQLiteDBUse(getActivity());
                        long result = db.updateName("4", in_patients_name[position]);
                        if (result > -1) {

                            Snackbar.make(view, in_patients_name[position] + " Removed", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            activePatientList.remove(position);
                            activePatientRecyclerAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                       return false;
                }

                ;
            });
            popupMenu.show();

        }
    });
    activePatientsList.setAdapter(activePatientRecyclerAdapter);

    return view;
}
```

Tab 2 Fragment :

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_out_patient, container, false);


    outPatientList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.out_patients_recyclerview);
    outPatientList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    patientListRecyclerAdapter = new PatientListRecyclerAdapter(getActivity()
            , patientList);
        }
    });
    outPatientList.setAdapter(patientListRecyclerAdapter);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    patientListRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: please post corresponding code..

Comment: some code would be helpful, however I am assuming that you are calling the notifyDataSetChanged() from main thread! right?

Comment: thanks for responding I have posted my code. hope it will help to solve it

Comment: the fragment onResume is being hit when you swipe to it? I don't believe thats the actual case since onResume() is called only when Activity onResume called

Comment: post your on tab change listener code, this would be the place to update the fragment using a public method, since your fragments are both created and maintained in a pager, none of the lifecycle methods are being called when you switch between views.

Comment: i have not used tab change listener, can you tell me where to use it and how ?